# How can I stop Open Office Calc from changing the data?

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-calc

I am using Apache Open Office Calc to view CSV data. I just noticed that Calc rounds the data on saving, reducing its precision, or at least I think that's what's going on.
I show below the same data before and after being viewed in Calc.

I definitely do not want my spreadsheet software altering the data. Is there a way to prevent this?

```
1.00785320895385,0.599046160391376,0.0136405658704284,0.950568994765312,4.525232155397,242,132.70240348559
1.007853209,0.5990461604,0.0136405659,0.9505689948,4.5252321554,242,132.7024034856
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Procedure:** Open OpenOffice Calc. Go to Tools > Options > OpenOffice Calc > Calculate > Enable Limit decimals for general number format > Enter Decimal Places (in digit) > Click OK.

[image: openoffice-calc-option-limit-decimal]

**Source:** [OpenOffice Wiki: Automatic decimal place adjustment](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Calc/Features/Automatic_decimal_place_adjustment)

Comment: I am curious why you set the decimal places to 14. Is this a special number, or did you just pick it arbitrarily?

Comment: @Argent That one just for example. Readers will catch easily.